# Getting full file attributes for files managed by Microsoft OneDrive

Tags: winapi, attributes, onedrive, ntfs, reparsepoint

Microsoft OneDrive allows file to be stored either locally, remotely or in the both ways. This is determined by new file attributes which appeared in the Windows 10:

```
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_PINNED                0x00080000  
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_UNPINNED              0x00100000  
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_RECALL_ON_OPEN        0x00040000  
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_RECALL_ON_DATA_ACCESS 0x00400000
```

as well as some file attributes inherited from previous versions of Windows:

```
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SPARSE_FILE           0x00000200
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT         0x00000400  
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_OFFLINE               0x00001000
```

Problem is that I cannot find a way to retrieve these new file attributes via Win32 API or NT Native API. I've tried so far:

```
GetFileAttributes()
FindFirstFile()
NtQueryAttributesFile()
```

For OneDrive file which was set to be stored always remotely, all these methods return 0x00500020 whilst true attributes are 0x00501620 (REPARSE_POINT, SPARSE_FILE and OFFLINE are masked out). True file attributes can be retrieved using the following PowerShell command:

```
[Convert]::ToString( (Get-ItemProperty -Path 'C:\Users\username\OneDrive\test.txt').Attributes.Value__, 16 )
```

`attrib.exe` system command is also able to display some of these new OneDrive-related file attributes (`O` for offline, `U` for unpinned, `P` for pinned).

Is there a way to retrieve these file attributes in my software? Maybe I need to add something to the manifest?

Comment: In my experience those attributes are definitely returned by `GetFileAttributes()`.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge the "recall" attributes may _only_ be exposed when traversing the folder hierarchy. They seem to be synthesized by the file system driver or a filter driver in the same stack (filter driver is actually more likely). But I could be wrong, investigating the topic myself right now. I suppose your manifest will also have to declare compatibility with Windows 10 at least ... otherwise you'd also get different behavior in other APIs as well.

Comment: Also see [RtlIsCloudFilesPlaceholder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/nf-ntifs-rtliscloudfilesplaceholder) and [RtlIsPartialPlaceholder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/nf-ntifs-rtlispartialplaceholder) ... they also got "recently" (I think 1709 or so?) exposed in ntdll.dll, not just inside ntoskrnl.exe ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From MSDN RtlSetThreadPlaceholderCompatibilityMode

> When placeholders are exposed, characteristics such as the presence of
>   a reparse point, the sparse bit, and the offline bit are plainly
>   visible through directory enumeration and other types of file
>   information queries. When placeholders are disguised, these details
>   are completely hidden, making the file look like a normal file.
>
> Most Windows applications see exposed placeholders by default. For
>   compatibility reasons, Windows may decide that certain applications
>   see disguised placeholders by default.

I am guessing that Windows has placed your test program in some sort of compatibility mode and is therefore filtering the attributes.

[RtlSetThreadPlaceholderCompatibilityMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-rtlsetthreadplaceholdercompatibilitymode)

Comment: There are indeed shims which an admin could assign to programs or which sometimes MS seems to assign to enable this mode. Thanks for the pointer to the function.