# How do I modify only "Storage on disk" property of a file

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, filesystems

I am trying to find ways to manage system storage efficiently.

One thing I've noticed while using **MS OneDrive** is that whenever I click "Free up space" on its context menu, it converts the "Storage on disk" to 0 bytes while its File size remains the same. I want to mimic what is happening over there.

Then I researched to see if I can partially modify its attribute (allocation size) through `SetFileInformationByHandle` using `FileAllocationInfo` as its parameter. It succeeded but both of its file size and allocation size became 0.

Test code as follows:

```
    WCHAR wcsDebug[2048];

    // testfile is 1224 bytes
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(_TEXT("C:\\test\\testfile.txt"), GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
    if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        FILE_ALLOCATION_INFO allocInfo;
        ZeroMemory(&allocInfo, sizeof(FILE_ALLOCATION_INFO));
        
        BOOL fResult = SetFileInformationByHandle(hFile,
            FileAllocationInfo,
            &allocInfo,
            sizeof(FILE_ALLOCATION_INFO));

        // after the execution, the size becomes 0
        if (fResult)
        {
            swprintf_s(wcsDebug, _countof(wcsDebug), L"SetFileInfomationByHandle() Success.");
            OutputDebugString(wcsDebug);
        }
        else
        {
            swprintf_s(wcsDebug, _countof(wcsDebug), L"SetFileInfomationByHandle() Failed. Err(%08X)", GetLastError());
            OutputDebugString(wcsDebug);
        }
    }
```

Any more ideas on developing the thoughts?

Comment: If i'm not mistaken, OneDrive and similar services are utilizing [ProjFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/projfs/projected-file-system). So it just reports arbitrary file parameters.

Comment: @user7860670 are you saying those properties do not represent its real properties?

Comment: I'm not sure, but i strongly suspect so.

Comment: This question seems to be the result of a fundamental misunderstanding on how things work. Changing the *"Storage on disk"* property **changes the actual file**. You've essentially purged the entire file contents. If you want to allow the local filesystem to act as a cache for cloud-stored files, use the [Cloud Filter API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cfapi/cloud-filter-reference) (which is how OneDrive is implemented). Likely, this is a duplicate of [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68137435/1889329).

Comment: lets `GetFileInformationByHandle` before and after your `SetFileInformationByHandle` and print some information to compare them.

Comment: *"I want to mimic what is happening over there."* -- so  you want to take a local file -- a file that exists only on your local drive -- and remove it from your local drive without removing it from cloud storage? Ermm... maybe you should write out real technical specs instead of using vague terms like "mimic".

Comment: @IInspectable You're right. I think I got the whole concept wrong. I will look into the APIs you've linked.

Comment: To "free up space" all you have to do is clear the `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_PINNED` attribute and set the `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_UNPINNED` attribute.